# Searching Win2008 R2 chipset driver for a lenovo idea centre K330

Tags: windows, drivers, motherboard, chipset

I have here a Lenovo Desktop and I dont know what chipset driver I need. If Im reading the information with AIDA there is:

Motherboard Name: **Lenovo IdeaCentre K330**

- if I search on the lenovo support site for the IdeaCentre K330 I find just the chipset driver for Win XP. Thats weird. Any ideas? Thank you

Maybe this will help

North Bridge: **Intel Sandy Bridge-DTIMC**

South Bridge: **Intel Cougar Point P67**

Intel Platform: **Sugar Bay**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched [Lenovo's support site](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/DriversDownloads/drivers_list.aspx?CategoryID=728080), and I see two Intel Chipset Driver downloads for the IdeaCentre K330.  One for [Windows XP](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/DriversDownloads/drivers_show_4091.html), and one for [Windows 7 32 bit/64 bit](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/DriversDownloads/drivers_show_3997.html).  The Windows 7 drivers should work fine for you.  Thanks @Ramhound for pointing out that I shouldn't answer questions for people first thing in the morning.

Comment: Why are you talking about Windows 8 when the author didn't even mention it?

Comment: @Ramhound My bad, I'll fix that.  Thanks for pointing that out and NOT fixing it for me.  Every day, someone here proves why I get annoyed helping out around here.  Nothing like elitism and preferential treatment to wake someone up.

Comment: pfft. Some of us *do* edit these things, and upvote good answers. Lenovo's website really is the first port of call when it comes to drivers for anything they make - thankfully they kept up the good work IBM did. I do hope if the downvote was for that little mistake, whoever did it undoes it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hell no, it's not going to go away.  Nothing like getting a sharp stick in the eye by a butt-hurt elitist.  From what I see, more of you don't edit these things than do.  More of you decide not to upvote good answers for personal reasons, than to rise above any pettiness.  But hey, if more of you did *that*, I wouldn't have anything to talk about, hey?

Comment: Im very careful with Win 7 drivers for Sever 2008 R2. If you try to download the network drivers, what is also for Win 7 64bit - I get the errormessage that this Driver is not working on this (win server 2008 r2) operating system. And the posten driver on the page is of the year 2011 - Im sure there is a newer one. Thats why I would download the newest from the intel download site. But no idea for what driver I should search there.